# Fetch an particular attribute from a resource using Query Language

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How to fetch a particular attribute from a resource using Query Language.

For example, for all the Employees, I need fetch email from the Employee participant. (Similar to get specific columns in the table: SELECT email from the employee)

There is a sample query in the doc to fetch all Employee attributes.

```
query Q1{
  description: "Select all Employees older than"
  statement:
      SELECT org.acme.Employee
}
```

Answer (score 2):

selecting individual fields in a SELECT not presently supported. Feel free to add an issue for this. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I have raised an issue